# Inflater in Android Fragments

Tags: android, layout-inflater

View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.check_fragment,container,false);

What is the use of a bool as in this case false ? 
I am a beginner to Android Programming , can someone explain this to me in detail ? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html

If you set it as true, then the view will be automatically added to its parent (second param). It most of times it should be false, but sometimes it is needed especially when you're using `<merge>` as root in inflated xml.

Comment: I didn't understand the second statement but first one is clearly understood to me and that's enough for me.       Thanks :) .

Comment: No problem, the merge is explained here in docs http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

Answer (score 0):

`true` means "please add the inflated `View` to `container` as a child for me". `false` means "please do not add the inflated `View` to `container` as a child for me, as other code will handle that later on".

In the case of fragments, you allow the `FragmentManager` to control adding and removing the fragment's `View` from its container.

The reason why you need `container` at all in `inflate()` is because certain layout manager classes (notably `RelativeLayout`) need to know their container in order to set up their layout rules properly.

Comment: Thanks.  I understood to some extent , I think i will better understand with experience :) .

Answer (score 0):

Whether the inflated hierarchy should be attached to the root parameter? If false, root is only used to create the correct subclass of LayoutParams for the root view in the XML.

Answer (score 0):

From [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean)):

> attachToRoot - Whether the inflated hierarchy should be attached to the
>   root parameter? If false, root is only used to create the correct
>   subclass of LayoutParams for the root view in the XML.

In fragments you should pass false as an attach argument, this way the view hierarchy will not be attached to the ViewGroup parent passed in the onCreateView. This attachment will happen later on, Android will take care of it. The container is only passed to onCreateView so you can know about the container where your fragments view hierarchy is going to go.

Actually setting this parameter to true will likely cause exceptions or at least some strange behaviour.